# yarn error code 1 when i create a react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

when i create a react app with npx create-react-app name and o try to yarn start that app i got error with exit code 1 to be more specific this is that one

```
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/tudor/node_modules/webpack-dev-server (version: 3.10.3) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/tudor/node_modules/webpack-dev-server is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack-dev-server in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack-dev-server.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and if i try to start an older app works i try to make that steps but still got error

Comment: Have you done anything that the error message suggests that you should do?

Comment: how i said yes i made all of them

Comment: Did you understand what steps 6 and 7 mean?

Comment: i think but if you can to explain better to verify if i made that good maybe will help me

Comment: also i created more react projects and got the same error

Comment: also my npm i see dont work idk why like 2 days ago all was fine

Comment: The error message says that you have an old version of webpack-dev-server in the folder /Users/tudor/node_modules/webpack-dev-server that it tries to use. If you delete that folder it should be fixed.

Comment: i made that and still dont work the problem is not in that project files i think because if i even create a new react project i got the same error

Comment: That is not a project file, it literally says that the version is outside the project files. Note that it doesn't say it's the project's node_modules folder, it's the one in the home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the webpack-dev-server by `yarn remove webpack-dev-server` and install the version 3.11.0 as `yarn add webpack-dev-server@3.11.0`

Comment: i made the same thing i installed the new webpack dev server with npm and worked how i said above but thanks. <3

Comment: there is nod different  between  npm and  yarn  no problem

Answer (score 0):

done i installed webpack-dev-server with `npm i webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 0):

None of above answers worked for me, only `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` I'm afraid.